# How to copy array to structure with fixed array?

Tags: c#

What is the best way for Copying 'mydata' to 'sample_a'?

I expect to get 4 in sample_a.data_array[ 1 ]. That value is p[ 9 ].

I plan to use this for TCP/UDP packet communication.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SampleA
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    public unsafe fixed char data_array[3];
    public int data3;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    short bytesize = 15; 
    byte[] mydata = new byte[bytesize];
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p = mydata)
        {
            // data1
            p[0] = 1;
            // data2
            p[4] = 2;
            // data_array
            p[8] = 3;
            p[9] = 4;
            p[10] = 5;
            // data3
            p[11] = 6;
        }

        // Copy 'mydata' to 'sample_a'
        IntPtr intptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytesize);
        Marshal.Copy(mydata, 0, intptr, bytesize);
        SampleA sample_a = (SampleA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(intptr, typeof(SampleA));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intptr);

        // I want to get 4 in a1
        int a1 = (int)sample_a.data_array[1];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also check the [MemoryMarshal.Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=netcore-3.1) this doesn't do a memory copy.

Comment: Thank you. I check your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that C#'s chars are 2 bytes wide, and you're treating them as if they're 1 byte wide.

One fix is to explicitly declare them as `byte`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SampleA
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    public unsafe fixed byte data_array[3];
    public int data3;
}
```

It's more common to embed arrays using `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SampleA
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] data_array;
    public int data3;
}
```

If you want to use `char`, you can tell the marshaller that each should be marshalled as a `U8`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SampleA
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public char[] data_array;
    public int data3;
}
```

You can also tell the marshaller that you're using ANSI strings, which has the same effect

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct SampleA
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public char[] data_array;
    public int data3;
}
```

Comment: That is one of several ways of doing this; however, it is not the only option

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid a lot of work here with spans:

```cs
// note: size is 18; if you intended 15 - perhaps change char=>byte
byte[] mydata = new byte[Unsafe.SizeOf<SampleA>()];
// alternative: Span<byte> mydata = stackalloc byte[Unsafe.SizeOf<SampleA>()];

// ..TODO: populate mydata

// cast it out
var sample_a = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, SampleA>(mydata)[0];
```

You can also use `Unsafe.As`, but this is IMO not a good idea as it won't detect incorrect memory conditions as well:

```cs
var sample_a = Unsafe.As<byte, SampleA>(ref mydata[0]);
```

Comment: Note also that this doesn't use the marshaller, and so none of the attributes which normally affect the marshaller, e.g. `MarshalAs`, will do anything.

Comment: @canton7 not true; `StructLayout` also impacts the layout of the struct itself: so yes, it still has effect (it won't impact `MarshalAs` - that was a comment edit, though!)

Comment: True, bad example on my side. Changed.

Comment: @canton7 re the bytes vs char: yes, that is true; if OP intends these to be bytes: they should declare them as bytes